# Add Controller on Plugin

Tags: plugins, controller, aspnetboilerplate

I use the example([sample plugin app](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/modular-todo-app/blob/master/src/todo-module/TodoModule.Web/TodoWebModule.cs#L17))to startup schema plugin. So we have a simple issue on controller inside plugin (DLL web). My controller is TemplateController when I try to call from web
http://localhost:6240/Template/Index does't fire. If I move it into web, main site it works fine.
I need to register some file/dll during startup. WepApi works fine

on dll web plugin

```
public override void Initialize()
    {
        //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
```

Comment: There is already a Controller inside the sample plugin (TodosController - https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/modular-todo-app/blob/master/src/todo-module/TodoModule.Web/Controllers/TodosController.cs) which works fine. What's the difference of your TemplateController?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to security. Try running web application as "Local System" in IIS Application Pool identity

Comment: But the problem is that Controller not create a valid route on IIS. I check it with Glimpse

Answer (score 0):

Do you have custom routes configured for controllers actions?
If so have you tried to add routes mapping to your module configuration?
Following example is for WebApi controllers

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    // your configuration here               
    Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```